# Вставка ссылки в ajax скрипт

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp, spring-mvc

**Всем привет!**

У меня есть приложение на Spring MVC и так на странице таблица с учебными предметами и форма добавления нового предмета. При добавлении нового предмета, он без перезагрузки появляется в списке. Но у меня ошибка при вставке ссылки сбоку от названия предмета ссылка на редактирование и удаление

Скрипт:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#saveSubject').submit(function (e) {
        $.post('/university/subjectAdd', $(this).serialize(), function (subject) {
            $('#subjectsTableResponse').last().append(
                    '<tr>' +
                    '<td align=\"center\">' + subject.title + '</td>' +
                    '<td align=\"center\">' + '<a href=\"c:url value=\'/subject/update/{'+subject.id+'}\'/>' + Редактировать + '</a>'+'</td>'+
                    '<td align=\"center\">' + '<a href=\"c:url value=\'/subject/delete/{'+subject.id+'}\'/>' + Удалить + '</a>'+'</td>'+
                    '</tr>'
            );
        });
    });
});
```

Ошибка в браузере такая:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Редактировать is not defined
```

Но после перезагрузки страницы все ок, я подозреваю, что что-то не так с экранированием символов в ссылке, потому что, если убрать добавление ссылок и оставить просто названия предметов, то все ок работает без ошибок. Я хочу, чтобы ajax в ответ вставлял эту ссылку ">Удалить 
Как решить сию проблему ?

Comment: Слова Редактировать и удалить должны быть в кавычках что бы они были строками. сейчас у тебя js их воспринимает как переменные. Так что просто по бокам от этих слов убери '+ что бы было .....\'/>Редактировать</a>....

Comment: Andy, первое - спасибо за ответ. Второе- убрал ковычки по бокам, но, к сожалению, теперь в таблицу добавляется запись с пустыми полями, там где должны быть редактировать и удалить. Вот моя ссылка, которую мне надо, чтобы ajax вставил в таблицу при добавлении новой записи - <a href="<c:url value='/subject/delete/${subject.id}' />">Delete</a> не подскажешь как мне правильно ее указать в ответе, чтобы она корректно отображалась ?

Comment: Плюс к этому, после обновлении страницы ссылки начинают отображаться корректно

Answer (score 0):

Всем спасибо, проблема была во невнимательности, забыл добавить - ">